Truck driver abducts women and holds them in a cellar
I remember watching this movie when I was younger, maybe in the 90's or early 2000's and it seemed like it might have been a made for TV movie because I saw it on TV.  Anyway all I can remember was it was about a truck driver that would abduct women and keep one at a time in a cellar in a barn I believe and even though he did this he had a family that had no idea of what he was doing.  He acted like a regular good family man.  That's the most I remember but I think his last victim ends up fighting back and killing him?

Please clarify which bit of the movie is "horror".

I think that might be Breakdown (1997) with Kurt Russell, J. T. Walsh, Kathleen Quinlan, and M. C. Gainey.  It has the "good family man" truck driver who has a barn where he "processes" women he captured.  Kurt Russell's character recovers his wife and puts and end to the conspiracy.

@coleopterist:  I hadn't seen other identify-this-movie questions provide such, but I have added some details.

@wallyk "I hadn't seen other identify-this-movie questions provide such, but I have added some details." - Some do though, the good ones in fact, which yours now also is. Apart from that, an ID question is probably not a bad example for the case when it is better to post separate answers if you see two different unrelated possibilities. So feel free to split this up and give the OP and others the chance to reason about the probability (and maybe finally acceptance) of each those two answers individually.

@ChristianRau:  Thanks for the suggestion!

It could be The Vanishing (1993) with Keifer Sutherland, Sandra Bullock, and the villain played by Jeff Bridges.  I don't recall a barn, but the villain has a panel truck (or is it an RV?) which he uses to abduct Sandy's character—apparently his only victim.  He also has a cabin in remote woods where he buries her.  It takes Keifer's character years to track him down and get revenge, whereas Breakdown occurs in the period of a day or so, so I think this is the less likely possibility.
